# How to let PyCharm accept my self-signed SSL certificate?

Tags: java, python, pycharm

I need PyCharm (2019.1, on macOS High Sierra) to accept my self-signed SSL certificate when connecting to a remote secure Jupyter notebook server. (https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html)

I've tried

1. Add the certificate file to Preferences/Tools/Server Certificates.
2. `keytool -import -alias cacerts -file jupytercert.pem` (I think that will probably allow the JRE that PyCharm relies on to accept the certificate)

Neither resolves the problem. When attempting a connection, an error prompts:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

P.S. The certificate was generated using:
`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout jupyterkey.key -out jupytercert.pem`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu, using the snap installation method.

I was able to fix the issue by first adding the custom certificate to my local java keystore with:

```
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts \
   -storepass changeit -noprompt -file path/to/my/certificate.crt  -alias my_cert_alias
```

Then I had to override the keystore used by pycharm in the snap using my local keystore. I could do that with a mount, as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/1036611/143257:

```
sudo mount --bind -o nodev,ro /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts \
    /snap/pycharm-professional/136/jre64/lib/security/cacerts
```

May there be a bug on Pycharm 2019, where the certificates for jupyter notebook access are not checked through the "Preferences/Tools/Server Certificates" filter?

My suggestion to you would be to find where does pycharm store its keystore on macOS and add the custom certificate there.

Comment: For reference, the PyCharm bug is tracked at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35376.